# How do I load real-world map terrain?

Tags: 2d, unity, maps, terrain

I'm new to game development and want know how to make or load a terrain from OpenStreetMap or Google Maps in your current city. (I'm using Unity3D.)

My idea is just load or generate a map of the current location, without collisions or anything else. A good example could be the Google's game "Ingress".

I found a few tutorials but only for a static city or mountain.

Comment: openstreetmap has a [dev wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop)